# Select rows where smaller row does not exist

Tags: oracle-11g

Consider the following table data:

```
ID NAME
1 Kshitiz 
2 Aman
5 Aakash
6 Manjeet
```

Here there are records missing between 2 and 5. What query can I use to select row 5 in this table?

Comment: What is row5. The row where ID=5?

Comment: @miracle173 Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle supports [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm) so you should be able to do something like.

```
SELECT T.ID, 
       T.NAME
FROM
(
SELECT ID, 
       NAME,
       LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS PREVID
FROM YourTable
) T
WHERE ID > PREVID + 1;
```

To compare the Id with the previous one and only return ones with a gap greater than 1.

(Untested as SQL Fiddle is currently returning errors when I try and create an Oracle Fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p2.ID,
  p2.NAME
FROM person p1
  INNER JOIN person p2 ON p1.ID = p2.ID+1
WHERE p1.ID <> p2.ID 
  AND p2.ID <> 1
```

You can join the table on itself having `ID = ID+1`

The `AND p2.ID <> 1` should only be there if 1 is the lowest value in the ID column.

[SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/578aa6/1)